# Некорректная работа регулярного выражения

Tags: c#, регулярные-выражения

Есть регулярное выражение, с помощью которого убирается строка формата "число-число месяц":

```
string reg = @"\s[\d]{0,2}\s?[-]?\s?\d{0,2}\s(янв|фев|мар|апр|(мая|май)|ию[нл]|авг|сент|окт|‌​ноя|дек)[\w]*";
```

Данное выражение не работает с ноябрем. Хотя если поменять местами "но" и "дек" - работает, но перестает работать с декабрем. 
В связи с чем возможна такая некорретная работа? Все символы перепроверил - кириллица.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Перед словом "ноя" есть пара невидимых символов (80 8b). В них и причина. Перевведите этот кусок аккуратно.

Comment: Вот мне интересно, а за что минус ставили:) Или просто по галочке промазали

Comment: спасибо, помогло. Как Вы нашли эти символы?

Comment: просто скопировал и вставил в regex101.com. Дальше - дело техники.